# Setting a threshold in classifier output in Python

Tags: python, classification

Assuming I have a trained SVM classifier in Python with the flag "Probability=True" as:

```
classifier = SVC(C = 1000000, gamma = 10, probability=True) 
classifier.fit(my_data, the_labels)
```

When I perform classification of new data, I want to keep only the classified new data whom probabilities are higher than a threshold, let's say 0.90. How can i do that? Till now I am doing something like this but I am stuck:

```
labels_predicted = classifier.predict(new_data)
probabilities = classifier.predict_proba(new_data)
```

The first command returns the actual labels and the second returns the probability of its label. So, for every data point, I have its maximum likelihood label and all its related probabilities belonging to all the labels. But the maximum likelihood label maybe 0.4 which i don't want it. How can i keep only the labels with a certain threshold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, SVC itself does not allow thresholding of probabilities in the manner you want. You can do a second pass of indexing and get the accepted labels after you build `labels_predicted` and `probabilities`.

```
thresh = 0.9
accepted_probabilities_idx = probabilities.max(axis=1) > thresh
accepted_labels_predicted = labels_predicted[accepted_probabilities_idx]
accepted_new_data = pandas.DataFrame(new_data, index=accepted_probabilities_idx)
```

I am not sure what you want to do with data where ML-probability with low. This solution discards it completely.

Comment: I want to consider the data where the probability to get assigned to a label is below 0.9 as outliers.

Comment: Ok, then above solution is fine, everything outside `accepted_new_data` is an outlier.

Comment: to use pandas.Dataframe which package should i import?

Comment: `import pandas`. It could very well be possible that your `new_data` is already a DataFrame. Simply check `new_data.__class__` on python console. If It is a DataFrame, you can remove `pandas.DataFrame` from the code.

Comment: In your answer, the 3rd line gives an error:   ValueError: boolean index array should have 1 dimension

Comment: I think your code is slightly incorrect. Assuming that new_data.shape is 1000 by 25, labels_pred is 1000 and probabilities is 1000 by 37 (let's say the number of labels).

Comment: Aah ok.. `predict_proba` returns a matrix of probabilities, but it shouldn't be hard to compute max of every row: Change line 2 to `accepted_probabilities_idx = probabilities.max(axis=1) > thresh`